# google maps beginner tutorial region

Tags: google-maps

I am just following the tutorial on google's website on how to use their API. I found this code and am trying to get it to work for any other country than the default but it isn't:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=personalKey&sensor=false&language=ar&region=ES">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

from what it says this should work simply. I am trying to get Spain to display on map rather than current choice.

The link am following: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics

Thanks,

Comment: Look at the line which assign center to coordinates. You should fill it with the coordinates for Spain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the values you're passing to `google.maps.LatLng()` to some close to where you want to display (eg., `goggle.maps.LatLng(40.813797402839086, -3.62546328124995)` for Madrid, according to [LatLng](http://www.latlng.org)).

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the position of the map by setting the region. You still need to change the co-ordinates to those of Spain.

Try: 40.6986° N, 3.2949° W